# jQuery doesn't get loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to coding, but made this site a few years ago and it stopped working a month ago. No changes were made. Please help. I tested the site by putting everything in DW and it worked. So I am not sure why on the web it wont replicate.

I did try all browsers and java is enabled. This is supposed to be a rotating picture wheel from coding jack. Like I said before it did work for the past 3 years. It stopped working a month or so ago.

I have been trying everything on my end to figure it out, but I am at a loss. Any help will be appreciated, but please understand I am not an expert. I did my research and will respond to you once I have tried everything you guide me with.

Thank you!

[results on webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoGx7.png)

```
<div class="zoom-gallery" id="zoom-instance-1">
    <img src="images/showcase/assets/preloader.gif" class="preloader" width="55" height="18" alt="preloader" />
    <ul>
        <li title="images/showcase/pastor1.jpg">
            <!-- "class" options are "align-left" and "align-right", these are the text-align options -->
            <!-- "title" attribute is optional.  If added it will link the entire slide to the url entered -->
            <ul class="align-left" title="http://codecanyon.net/user/CodingJack">
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li title="images/showcase/child.jpg">
            <ul class="align-left">
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li title="images/showcase/prayer.jpg">
            <ul class="align-left">
            </ul>
        <li title="images/showcase/praise.jpg">
            <ul class="align-left">
            </ul>
            <ul class="align-left">
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <noscript>
        <div id="noscript"><img src="images/showcase/pastor1.jpg" alt="jQuery Banner Rotator" width="400" height="262" align="middle" />
        </div>
    </noscript>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: You haven't provided any pertinent information to allow us to figure out the problem. A screenshot of a broken page and short HTML sample won't suffice.

Comment: Incomplete Information.

Comment: `java` has nothing to do here. Provide the link to the live website.

Comment: Put your full html to here https://jsfiddle.net/ or publish your website URL.